# Missing data coded as NA and "NA"

Tags: r

I have a data set containing a factor variable "gender" in a data frame. Missing Data for gender is coded . When I run fix(mydata) I find that the cell is actually empty.

I am aware of the is.na function and have revised a function seen on the web to replace missing data by 9. I am anticipating having more data, perhaps even more factor variables which may have missing data. The function works just fine for numeric data but when I use factor data as input I get no error but no change in the missing data item either that is it is not being recoded to 9.

```
Modified Function:
na.nine <- function (x) {
    x[is.na(x)] <- 9
    return(x)
}
mydata1$gender=na.nine(mydata1$gender)
```

The result is no recoding of  and a warning message:
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, is.na(x), value = 9) :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
Output shows that  is not being changed at all.

I need to protect this data. It belongs to someone else or I would include more.

If I were doing a statistical study I would drop a row containing a factor variable with missing data but what if I were asked to replace the < NA > to 9?
Without using fix(mydata1) and changing the 's one at a time I don't know how to do this? What if I had 5000 observations to check?

Any help here would be appreciated. Thanks.  MM

Comment: It appears that you may not need to do any this, because `NA` has been assigned already. Your code would not make any difference. You could try `is.na(mydata1$gender)` before running your code to check this. My understanding is  `<NA>` is NA for factor variables in a data frame, "NA" is just a string with letters N and A.

Comment: A reproducible example would have helped a lot to better understand the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert a factor to character first, replace, and convert back to factor if need be.

```
#Modified Function:
na.nine <- function (x,TOREPLACE,FACTOR=TRUE) {
    x <- as.character(x)
    x[is.na(x)] <- TOREPLACE
    # if character is ok
    #return(x)
    return(factor(x))
}

mydata = data.frame(
gender=sample(c("M","F"),10,replace=TRUE),
age = sample(20:70,10,replace=TRUE)
)
# make some NAs
mydata$gender[1:3] <- NA
# use your function
mydata$gender <- na.nine(mydata$gender,9)
mydata
```

Comment: It works! Is TOREPLACE a special variable? Could I replace it with something else?  My data cleaning skills need working on... MM

Comment: oh, you can see na.nine(mydata$gender,9), the first entry is your variable, 9 is what you want to replace NA with. So if say you want to replace with "missing", do mydata$gender <- na.nine(mydata$gender,"Missing")

Comment: Thanks. These R functions are similar to SAS macros.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any example data here, but this should work to address what I believe the problem is.

```r
## This will also show NAs in the sample as well as "NA"s
table(paste(mydata1$gender))


## Lets just keep "m" & "f" values with all else becoming NA
mydata1$gender<-ifelse(mydata1$gender=="m" | mydata1$gender=="f", mydata1$gender, NA)


## This is the corrected output where only "m" & "f" remain
table(paste(mydata1$gender))
```

Comment: This approach is not working for me. I have revised the post in an attempt to clarify this. Thank you for your comment.  MM

Comment: It looks like converting it to a character to address the NAs then back to factor to relevel it would be the best way.

Comment: I need to apply table(paste(mydata1$gender)) to my code. The paste function here does what? This is taking a bit of study.